# When is $\frac{2^{2915}}{5n+1}$ an integer?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am looking for the number of integers n for which the fraction $$\frac{2^{2915}}{5n+1}$$ is an integer. Any help?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you considered putting in a few values for $n$?  What happens?

Comment: The number of divisors of $2^{2915}$ of the form $5n+1$. Since $2$ is a generator for $\mathbb{Z}/(5\mathbb{Z})^*$...

Comment: Well, the only divisors of $2^m$ are $2^k$ so we must solve $2^k \equiv 1 \mod 5$ which occurs when $k $ is ... what?

Answer (score 4):

Interesting question. As Jack D'Aurizio pointed in the comments, it is the number of divisors of $2^{2915}$ of the form $5n+1.$ Since the only divisors of a power of two are the smallest powers of two, we are looking for how many $n\in \Bbb N$ there exists $k\in \Bbb N,\; k\leq 2915,$ such that $5n+1=2^k.$ Note that this is equivalent to find for how many $k \in \Bbb N,\ k\leq 2915,$ is $2^k \equiv 1 \mod 5.$  Now, note that

\begin{align*}
  2^0 &\equiv 1 \mod 5 \\
  2^1 &\equiv 2 \mod 5 \\
  2^2 &\equiv 4 \mod 5 \\
  2^3 &\equiv 3 \mod 5\\
  2^4 &\equiv 1 \mod 5\\
\end{align*} From there you deduce that $2^k\equiv 1 \mod 5$ iff $k\equiv 0 \mod 4.$ Now we just have to find how many multiples of 4 are less than $2915.$ It is easy to see that this quantity is just the greatest integer less than or equal to $2915/4=728.75,$ so the number we are searching is only $729$ ($728+1$ because $n=0$ is allowed). This means that there are $729$ values of $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $\frac{2^{2915}}{5n+1}$ is an integer. Hope this helps.

Comment: I think there is an off-by-one: we are allowed to take $n=0$, so there should be $729$ solutions.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Yep, I will fix it. Thanks

Comment: I think we have a doubling scenario as well, since $n=-1$ gives $5n+1=-4$...

Comment: Good point.  You need $n = \frac {\pm 2^{4m}-1}5$ where $0 \le 4m \le 2915$.  So there are $1458$ solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The question calls for the number of integer values of

$$\frac{2^{2915}}{5n+1}.$$

The positive integer values are covered (as in the other answer) by $2^k\equiv 1\pmod 5$ which were found to be $k\equiv 0\pmod 4$.  For the negative integer values of $-2^k\equiv 1\pmod 5$ we see that we have $k\equiv 2\pmod 4$, which also yields the value $\frac{2915}4=728.75$.  Since the fraction $\frac{2916}4=729$ does not count an additional value for $k=2914$, we see that we have $729$ negative values of $k$ and $729$ positive values of $k$ for a total of $1458$ values of $n$ for which
$$\frac{2^{2915}}{5n+1}$$
is an integer.